# Do nearby members of my game benefit from the bonuses given by a shrine?

Tags: diablo-iii

I haven't started playing with others yet, but for when I do, will shrines I or others in my game activate benefit others in the vicinity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is indeed the case.

The distance is roughly a screen and a half on my resolution of 1920x1200 so there is a bit of leeway in this, but if they are out of the range then you just wasted the power of the shrine by the number of people that could have gotten it as well!